# TypoScript: Get image from pages.media root page - or how to use FAL in TypoScript with level sliding features in 7LTS?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

The page logo of a page should be stored in the root page as a media resource. The logo should then be displayed on top of the page using a TypoScript marker. This works so far:

```
lib.components.headerLogo = FILES
lib.components.headerLogo {
    references {
        table = pages
        uid.data = leveluid:0, slide
        fieldName = media
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        10 = IMAGE
        10 {
            file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the logo is not set, this solution will output a empty img tag instead:

```
<img src="" width="0" height="0" alt="">
```

How can I prevent this output? A normal `ifEmpty`didn't help, because there is an actual tag rendered.

Comment: Strange... I tried with both 7.6 and 8.7 and if I don't set a logo, I don't see an empty img tag :S

Comment: the problem to this mechanism is: the slide field is, according to typoscript syntax, the field `uid`. As that field is set for each page, there will be no sliding. the uid from the current page is taken. the interesting field `media` can not be configured to slide as only the fieldname is used.